# jquery upload - accessing responses with chunked fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery upload for chunked uploads. Creating a new file and first chunk in my php back-end goes fine, but for the rest chunks I need a file-ID to tell my php script where to append file data.

So my problem is I don't know a way to read the response (ie. file-id) from ajax with jquery upload and edit the post data, in this case add the file id to the requests after the first chunk. The responses seem to behave mysterically.

I console log in my progress-callback `console.log(data)` and I get a buch of stuff. I can log ie. `console.log(data._progress.field)` but cannot do this for **data._response.file-id** as console says **undefined**. But when i console log the whole data I can clearly see a _response -object inside data. but when I specifically try to log that I get `Object {  }` so it seems to be empty, but when i click it I see  **jqXHR**-object and **result**-object that has the file-id I want to put to post requests for the rest chunks.

TL,DR:

I can console.log whole **data** in callback and see the result ie. file-id, but when I try to log data.result.file-id, console says "undefined".
Some fields I can log but some I can't Ie. **data._progress.total** logs just fine but **data._result** doesn't.

I need a field from response and change the post parameters for the next requests of chunked file upload.

What on earth I am missing here?

**EDIT:**
I have found a back-end solution to my problem and I didn't need jQuery/ajax request response things I tried to use. This was proprietary works so sorry I can't post my code.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: Its at least 200 lines and would need screenshots. I don't have the time now to make pseudo code, sorry.